# View is presented modally instead of Show

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a TableViewController. When a cell is tapped, a `showEpisodes` segue is called. This segue is set as `Show` and pointed to a Navigation Controller, like this:

[image: Segue]

The problem is that my view shows modally, i.e it doesn't have a navigationcontroller.

Here is the code I use in Main Table View Controller

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showEpisodes", sender: cell?.textLabel?.text)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showEpisodes" {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let vc = viewController.topViewController as! EpisodesTableViewCOntroller
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let object: PFObject = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        vc.podcast = object
       // self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

}

If I uncomment the `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` part, the view will get pushed fine but as soon as it is loaded, a black window is modally presented over it. I've checked the UI Hierarchy in the debugger without success. Any ideas please?

Comment: When it presents as a modal, you said that it is no longer in a navigation controller? In your image it shows that you segue from your "Main Table View Controller" to another navigation controller...

Comment: That's correct, which is what I really don't understand.

Comment: A "show" segue uses a modal transition when you go from one navigation controller to another. Your "show" segue should use a push transition if you take your table view (the one with the play and download buttons in it) out of the navigation controller it is currently in.

Comment: Deleting the second navigation controller fixed it. Thank you. If you would like to submit as an answer I will upvote it.

Comment: Glad it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason that it is currently using a modal transition is because you are going from one navigation controller to another. It is standard for a "show" segue to present modally when you change navigation controllers. To make it transition with a push animation, you need to take the tableViewController that you are transitioning to out of the navigation controller.